# ORACLE SQL data from next recordset in current recordset

Tags: sql, oracle, recordset

```
SELECT
  tsn_ref,
  current_node
FROM rtdev.trip_bodies cnode
WHERE thr_id = 1
ORDER BY arrival_time
```

The above query gives me 9 records each with 2 columns, quite straigh forward
I want to add a 3rd column, which will contain the 'TSN_REF' field from the subsequent (time sorted) recordset.

So output would be along the lines of:

```
+---------+--------------+------+
| TSN_REF | CURRENT_NODE | TSN2 |
+---------+--------------+------+
|       1 |            1 | 2    |
|       2 |            2 | 4    |
|       4 |           10 | 8    |
|       8 |           13 | 13   |
|      13 |           16 | NULL | (no subsequent entry)
+---------+--------------+------+
```

Any suggestions on how I could modify the query to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the LEAD function:   http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php

it would go something like this (this is untested....)

```
 SELECT TSN_REF, 
        CURRENT_NODE,
        LEAD(TSN_REF, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY ARRIVAL_TIME) TSN2
   FROM RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES CNODE 
  WHERE (THR_ID = 1) 
  ORDER BY ARRIVAL_TIME
```

edited: fixed order by in lead

### Update

See if this works....

```
select ts_id,
       tsn_ref,
       current_node,
       case when ts_id = ts_id_next then tsn_ref_next else null end tsn_ref_next 
 from (
   with q as (
      select 1 ts_id, 1 tsn_ref,   1 current_node, sysdate - 20 arrival_time from dual
      union
      select 1 ts_id, 2 tsn_ref,   2 current_node, sysdate - 19 arrival_time from dual
      union
      select 1 ts_id, 4 tsn_ref,  10 current_node, sysdate - 18 arrival_time from dual
      union
      select 1 ts_id, 8 tsn_ref,  13 current_node, sysdate - 17 arrival_time from dual
      union
      select 1 ts_id, 13 tsn_ref, 16 current_node, sysdate - 16 arrival_time from dual
      union
      select 2 ts_id, 1 tsn_ref,   1 current_node, sysdate - 20 arrival_time from dual
      union
      select 2 ts_id, 2 tsn_ref,   2 current_node, sysdate - 19 arrival_time from dual
      union
      select 2 ts_id, 4 tsn_ref,  10 current_node, sysdate - 18 arrival_time from dual
      union
      select 2 ts_id, 8 tsn_ref,  13 current_node, sysdate - 17 arrival_time from dual
      union
      select 2 ts_id, 13 tsn_ref, 16 current_node, sysdate - 16 arrival_time from dual
     )
select ts_id, 
   tsn_ref, 
   current_node,
   lead(tsn_ref, 1, '') over (order by ts_id, arrival_time) tsn_ref_next,
   lag(ts_id, 1, ts_id) over (order by ts_id, arrival_time)    ts_id_next
from q
)
```

You will want to use your table, so something like this:

```
select ts_id,
       tsn_ref,
       current_node,
       case when ts_id = ts_id_next then tsn_ref_next else null end tsn_ref_next 
 from (
       select ts_id, 
              tsn_ref, 
              current_node,
              arrival_time,
              lead(tsn_ref, 1, '') over (order by ts_id, arrival_time) tsn_ref_next,
              lag(ts_id, 1, ts_id) over (order by ts_id, arrival_time)    ts_id_next
          FROM RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES CNODE 
         ORDER BY ARRIVAL_TIME  -- this order by may not be needed
     )
  ORDER BY ARRIVAL_TIME
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very close to the mark, except that TSN_REF is not necessarily always increasing. If I change it to LEAD(TSN_REF, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY ARRIVAL_TIME) TSN2 - it appears to work correctly. Now for some reading on the function, thanks.

Comment: Super!!!  That would make sense, as the table is ordered by arrival_time, so should the lead ordering.

Comment: 1 last complexity for it, the function is actually LEAD(TSN_REF) OVER (ORDER BY THR_ID,ARRIVAL_TIME), as there are 2 fields I sort the data on. This gives a continuous stream of values for TSN2 that are correct, except that when THR_ID changes, TSN2 should always be blank at this point. This could be done progamatically on the recordset, but would be tidier if the recordet already clears it upon the THR_ID change.

Comment: So thr_id can be 1 or 2? I think the easiest thing might be to union 2 queries.  See update...

Comment: thr_id has about 2000 entries, so a union would be nasty. The original query with LEAD works, ordering by both THR_ID and ARRIVAL_TIME, apart from the TSN2 value when THR_ID changes.

Comment: I was thinking that might be the case.  So it would be necessary to use 2 lead functions.  I just got a tech support call...gotta run...will try again asap.

Comment: See if the Update helps...this is the basic idea...hard to give an exact result without having more data.  I made some sample data to check the results, so far looking good.

Comment: Very close, change the lag to lead, and it works! 782 msec for 172k records, so reasonable execution speed also

Comment: Great!! It a lot harder when I am unfamiliar with the data and have a bit uncertainty with what the exact result requirements.  Glad I could get it close. Some indexing may help speed up the results. If you're running in toad, look at the explain plan and see if any full table scans happen and index the cols.  Not knowing the hardware/memory settings, I would ball park this to run sub 300ms with indexes placed on the correct columns.